# Can you printf value from a void * in C

Tags: c, pointers, void

Ok, I'm trying to do this, but it isn't working becuase I'm not dereferencing the pointer... is there a way to do it without making a switch statement for the type?

```
typedef struct
{
    char *ascii_fmtstr;
    int len;
    int (*deserializer)(void *in, const char *ascii);
    int (*serializer)(const void *in, char *ascii);
} FORMAT;

const FORMAT formats[]=
{
    {"%d\n",    2/2}        //Int
    ,{"%s\n",   STRSIZE/2}  //String
    ,{"%.4f\n", 4/2}        //Float
    ,{"%lld",   4/2}        //Long-Long
    ,{"%s\n",   STRSIZE/2}  //Time
};

typedef struct {
    int fmtindex;
    void * vp;
} JUNK;

float f = 5.0f;
int i=1;
char foo[]="bar";

JUNK j[] = {
     {2, &f}
     ,{0, &i}
     ,{1, foo}};

void dump(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        printf(formats[j[i].fmtindex].ascii_fmtstr, j[i].vp);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're using `void *` as a cheap `union`. That's a pretty bad idea. I think you'll find `union`s in conjunction with `enum`s and `switch`es make this *look* so much neater, in C. You'll find the `switch` amongst the `#ifdef SWITCH` ... `#else`, and the switchless version amongst the `#else` ... `#endif`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct object {
    enum type {
        d=0,
        s=1,
        f=2,
        lld=3,
        time=4
    } type;

    union instance {
        int d;
        char *s;
        float f;
        long long lld;
        char *time;
    } instance;
};

#ifdef SWITCH
void print_object(struct object *o) {
    switch (o->type) {
        case d: printf("%d", o->instance.d); break;
        case s: printf("%s", o->instance.s); break;
        case f: printf("%f", o->instance.f); break;
        case lld: printf("%lld", o->instance.lld); break;
        case time: printf("%s", o->instance.time); break;
    };
}
#else
void print_d(struct object *o);
void print_s(struct object *o);
void print_f(struct object *o);
void print_lld(struct object *o);
void print_time(struct object *o);

void print_object(struct object *o) {
    void (*print_functions[])(struct object *) = {
         [d] = print_d,
         [s] = print_s,
         [f] = print_f,
         [lld] = print_lld,
         [time] = print_time
    };

    print_functions[o->type](o);
}

void print_d(struct object *o) { printf("%d", o->instance.d); }
void print_s(struct object *o) { printf("%s", o->instance.s); }
void print_f(struct object *o) { printf("%f", o->instance.f); }
void print_lld(struct object *o) { printf("%lld", o->instance.lld); }
void print_time(struct object *o) { printf("%s", o->instance.time); }
#endif

int main(void) {
    struct object o = { .type = d,                /* type: int */
                        .instance = { .d = 42 }   /* value: 42 */ };

    print_object(&o);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's kind of a cheap union -- I'm trying to unite a modbus register area (everything is stored in a structure, and there's a "mapping structure" that has the void * and the type spec) with something that's human-readable (so I can "print" the modbus register and get something intelligent out).  I have a feeling that if I use with switch statement, the C compiler will be able to use cheaper printfs so maybe the extra code will actually be smaller.

Comment: @ThorMJ Do you have any evidence to suggest that this code is *too large* or *too slow*? In what form did you obtain it?

Comment: It's "too large" in source code size ;)... it's actually improved my code size a lot since I was able to discard the printf...

Comment: @ThorMJ The alternative is much *larger in source code size*, and certainly no more clear. Perhaps, if you wish to develop more clear code, it might be a good idea to focus on making your identifiers more descriptive and consistent. Can you justify using `ascii` in your identifiers when you compile this code on an IBM mainframe, which uses an EBCDIC character set?

Answer (score 2):

You can print the pointer itself with something like `%p` but, if you want to print what it points *to,* you need to tell it what it is:

```
printf ("%d", *((int*)myVoidPtr));
```

You're not allowed to dereference a `void *` simply because the compiler doesn't know what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way : `Any` pointer simply points to a **single** memory location.But the `type` of the pointer determines `how many` bytes after that to interpret/consider.If it is `char*` then (depending on system) 1 byte is interpreted,if it is an `int*` 4 bytes are interpreted, and so on.But a `void*` had `no type`.So you can't dereference a `void` pointer in C due to this simple reason.But you can print out the address it points to using the `%p` format specifier in `printf()` and passing that `void` pointer as argument.

```
printf("The address pointed by void pointer is %p",void_ptr); //Correct

printf("The address pointed by void pointer is %p",(void*)int_ptr);//Correct
```

assuming `int_ptr` is an integer pointer,say,and `void_ptr` is a void pointer.

```
printf("Value at address pointed by void pointer is %d",*void_ptr);// Wrong

printf("Value at address pointed by void pointer is %d",*(void*)int_ptr);//Wrong
```

Comment: This is true, but irrelevant to the OP's question. Since he is already passing type info in the format, `printf` has all the necessary information to dereference the pointer itself — if such a format existed. (This is in fact exactly how `scanf`, whose all arguments are pointers, works.) It doesn't, but it's an interface problem, not a fundamental deficiency of his approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your real goal is. Yes, there are ways to print data type dependent. Basically the idea is to create your own print function.

But only supplying the pointer will not be enough. In any case you need to supply pointer and the type of it.

Lets assume we have a function `myprint`:

```
myprint("%m %m %m %i", TYPE_INT, &i, TYPE_FLOAT, &f, TYPE_STRING, foo, 10);
```

would be a possible call. `myprint` is a varargs function then which needs to reconstruct the format string and arguments and then can call real `printf`.

If you use heap variables only, the type of the variable can be stored together with the data with some tricks (hint: check how `malloc` stores the block size). This would make the additional arguments superflous.

There are other solutions to that, but a good suggestion is not possible without knowledge of your real goal and the exact conditions.

Comment: I guess I was hoping I could do an "inverse scanf" to be neat and clean.  Nuts.

Comment: Can you explain how to "check how `malloc` stores the block size" in standard C? Also, how would this distinguish between an array of `char` the same size as an `int`, and an `int`, not to mention any other types that might have the same width?

Comment: Either read the implementation of malloc or find some documentation how mallocs memory layout works. Essentially the idea there is that a pointer does not necessarily need to point to the beginning of the allocated memory block. If you have own functions for allocation/deallocation, then you can use the negative offsets for own data. Anyway there are some constraints like proper alignment, no mixing of allocation, ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the `printf` and its friends (fprintf, etc.) can dereference only `char*` which will be interpreted as a c-string.

Actually you can write such function yourself, because you will tell your function how to dereference `void*` with format flags.

Also you can add to the `formats` as a third value a pointer to required  dereference function that will take as argument a `void*` and will return the value instead of pointer.
So you will need to write a function for each of the types you use in your formats and assign each function to each format properly.

Comment: `I don't thinks the printf and its friends can dereference from pointer except char* which will be interpreted as a sting` I did not understand what you mean by this. Please elaborate

Comment: @SuvP Changed my weird sentence to be more understandable.

Comment: Actually i still don't understand, I mean why can printf dereference only `char*` ? It can dereference `int*` etc too ?

Comment: @SuvP You can't pass the pointer to int as an argument of printf and print the value of that int. You need to pass the value of that int to printf. If you pass a pointer you can print the address where pointer points. But you can pass a pointer to char and print the value of that char and the next char and the next ... until '\0' will be found.

Comment: Ok i get it. If we use `char*` of a C-string `printf` can print until `\0` _iff_ it uses `%s`. Incase of `int*` etc you need to dereference explicitly to get the value

Comment: On a technical note, `printf` knows exactly how to deref an `int *` passed in correspondence with the `%n` directive.